# Are you Following the Official Project Management StackExchange Twitter Account?

Tags: discussion

If you're a Twitter fan and spend time retweeting questions, you may want to consider following @StackProjects.

https://twitter.com/#!/search/realtime/StackProjects

StackProjects is the official Project Management StackExchange Twitter account created by the StackExchange team. It's configured to automatically tweet certain questions. It looks like a question is tweeted almost daily, so it's not a lot of noise.

It could help expose PMSE to more of your followers and encourage us all to retweet more questions.