# Should the Twitter feed use the #pmot hash tag?

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, tags, promotion

There's currently a [@StackProjects account](https://twitter.com/StackProjects) that carries a [Twitter feed of questions](https://twitter.com/#!/search/realtime/StackProjects). A brief glance at the feed indicates that PMSE *may* be missing a bet when it comes to accessible its target audience.

There's a [#pmot](https://twitter.com/#!/search/#pmot) (project managers on Twitter) hash tag that, in my experience, is generally used for material that is of general interest to project managers across PM disciplines and methodologies. I would think that most on-topic questions on this site would fit that category.

Would it be both appropriate and technically feasible to add that hash tag (or even something better) to every feed post? If not, why not?

#### See Also

[Are you Following the Official Project Management StackExchange Twitter Account?](https://pm.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/334/are-you-following-the-official-project-management-stackexchange-twitter-account)

Comment: Be very, very careful of this.  The bot that puts the links with the questions out there has been known to make some *very* stupid mistakes and put out links to posts that are not very good (to my knowledge, you can't tell the bot when and which questions to post links to).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All questions on PM.SE that are tweeted now have the #pmot hashtag - and *only* the #pmot hashtag.

Answer (score 1):

I think it is worth trying the #pmot tag on the Twitter feed.